# localStorage variables says null when there is actually value

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-context

I have this code to render the Dashboard when it detects the username is "admin". But I am getting an error saying that the user.username has no value or null where in fact there is a value after it logged in in the localstorage.
Here's my code
i

```
mport { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext()

export const authReducer = (state, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
          case 'LOGIN':
               return { user: action.payload }
          case 'LOGOUT':
               return { user: null }    
          default:
               return state
     }
}

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
     const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, {
          user: null
     })

     useEffect(() => {
          const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))

          if(user){
               dispatch({type: 'LOGIN', payload: user})
          }
     },[])

     {console.log('AuthContext state:', state)}
     return (
          <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
               {children}
          </AuthContext.Provider>
     )
}


import { useState } from "react";
import { useAuthContext } from "./useAuthContext";


export const useLogin = () => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(null)
    const { dispatch } = useAuthContext()


    const login = async (username, password) => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        setError(null)

        const response = await fetch('/credentials/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
        })
        const json = await response.json()

        if(!response.ok){
            setIsLoading(false)
            setError(json.error)
        }
        else{
             
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(json))


            //update AuthContext
            dispatch({type: 'LOGIN', payload: json})

            setIsLoading(false)
        }
    }
    return { login, isLoading, error }

}
```

I set this to this if the user it gets is admin, then render the dashboard.

```
    const Home = () => {
    const { user } = useAuthContext()
    
    return (

        <div>
            <Container>

                <Routes>
                    <Route
                        path="/"
                        element={user.username=="admin" ? <Dashboard title="Dashboard" user="User" /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
                    />
```

But it crashes the system and got a "user.username is null" in the console

Comment: Please include your code as text, not images.

Comment: I will edit it. Sorry coz i don't know how to properly file it here.

Comment: hi @DBS. I already updated my code.

Comment: @kevthedevv consider including `useAuthContext` as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the context to start debugging this code, but it looks like the object `user` it's not defined
Try to log this user state and be sure that's filled with the user object data.

I see you used a ternary if to redirect the user, use the optional chaining to avoid error on null/undefined objects

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Put here the context code and check the wrapper around all of this